# PHP Regex Question

Tags: php, regex

Would it be possible to make a regex that reads {variable} like `<?php echo $variable ?>` in PHP files?

Thanks

Remy

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I don't know whether it is possible or not, but it sounds like a bad idea. Anyone else who looks at your code will have no clue what is going on, and your development tools will most likely also not understand it.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP manual already provides a [regular expression for variable names](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

```
[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*
```

You just have to alter it to this:

```
\{[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\}
```

And you’re done.

---

**Edit**   You should be aware that a simple sequential replacment of such occurrences [as Ross proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532850/php-regex-question/532937#532937) can cause some unwanted behavior when for example a substitution also contains such variables.

So you should better parse the code and replace those variables separately. An example:

```
$tokens = preg_split('/(\{[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*\})/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
for ($i=1, $n=count($tokens); $i<$n; $i+=2) {
    $name = substr($tokens[$i], 1, -1);
    if (isset($variables[$name])) {
        $tokens[$i] = $variables[$name];
    } else {
        // Error: variable missing
    }
}
$string = implode('', $tokens);
```

Comment: I think he wants to replace the php tags and also the echo function with the braces, not just the dollar sign.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to do some template variable replacement ;)

I'd advise collecting your variables first, in an array for example, and then use something like:

```
// Variables are stored in $vars which is an array
foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {
    $str = str_replace('{' . $name . '}', $value, $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

{Not actually an answer, but need clarification}

Could you expand your question?  Are you wanting to apply a regex to the contents of $variable?

Comment: i want to be able to type {variable} instead of <?php echo $variable ?>.

Comment: @Suroot: Comments are usually used for this kind of question :)

Comment: @Ross: Suroot doesn't have enough rep to post comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following line should replace all occurences of the string '`{variable}`' with the value of the global variable `$variable`:

```
$mystring = preg_replace_callback(
  '/\{([a-zA-Z][\w\d]+)\}/', 
  create_function('$matches', 'return $GLOBALS[$matches[1]];'), 
  $mystring);
```

**Edit:** Replace the regex used here by the one mentioned by Gumbo to precisely catch all possible PHP variable names.

Answer (score 0):

> ([in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532850/php-regex-question/532865#532865)) i want to be able to type `{variable}`
>   instead of `<?php echo $variable ?>`

*Primitive approach*: You could use an external program (e.g. a Python script) to preprocess your files, making the following regex substitution:

```
"{([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)}"
```

with

```
"<?php echo $\g<1> ?>"
```

*Better approach*: Write a macro in your IDE or code editor to automatically make the substitution for you.