# Get list of {} templates from String [PHP]

Tags: php, string, templates, variables

I want to get the template words in a string. Template in the sense of words in {} inside a string. I am adding here a code to explain what I want exactly.

```
$string = "Hi {username}, Here is your {password}";

function get_template_variables($string)
{

    ....
    ....
    return array();
}

$result = get_template_variables($string);
print_r($result);


array[
    0 => username,
    1 => password
    ]
```

I hope you understand what I need. I need the definition program to be used inside the `get_template_variables($string)` method

Comment: What’s the syntax for the part between `{` and `}`?

Comment: Maybe related: Take a look at [my answer on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532850/php-regex-question/532880#532880).

Answer (score 4):

```
function get_template_variables($string) {
    preg_match_all('/{([^}]+)}/', $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: No need to check whether `preg_match_all` found any matches, with the default *PREG\_PATTERN\_ORDER* mode `$matches[1]` is always an array.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
function get_template_variables($string) {

    if(preg_match_all('/\{(.*?)\}/',$string,$m)) {
        return $m[1]
    }
    return array();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! The above two methods are working. Sean Bright and Codaddict - real quick answers: Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('/{.*}/U' , $string  , $a );
```

where $result will be

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "{username}"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "{password}"
  }
}
```

Comment: damn, codaddict and MainMa were too quick for me !